# Excel VBA for each cell in range A, copy value in cell B, to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in Sheet1 like:
A1 = 23, B1 = M, C1 = 256
and for each value in range A, I need to copy value from cell B1 and C1 to Sheet2 into cell A6 and D7.

thank you very much for your help

Hello, yes. I tryed to make it like:

```
Sub Get_Data()  
    Dim lastrowDB As Long, lastrow As Long  
    Dim arr1, arr2, i As Integer  

    With Sheets("Hárok2")
         lastrowDB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    Sheets("Hárok1").Select
    arr1 = Array("B", "C", "D")
    Sheets("Hárok2").Select
    arr2 = Array("B3:C3", "B7:C7", "E7:F7")

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        With Sheets("Hárok1")
             lastrow = Application.Max(3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
             .Range(.Cells(3, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
             Sheets("Hárok2").Range(arr2(i) & lastrowDB).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        'Sheets("Hárok2").Select
        'Range("A1:L5").PrintOut  
    Next  
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

but it give me a error in line: Sheets("Hárok2").Range(arr2(i) & lastrowDB).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is overkill here I think. I am guessing you want it to continue from A6 and D7 on down. Obviously change worksheets as necessary. This is pulling from ws1 (source) to ws2 (destination).

```
Sub denn()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws1 = WorkSheets("Sheet4")
Set ws2 = WorkSheets("Sheet5")
lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    ws2.Cells(i + 5, 1) = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    ws2.Cells(i + 6, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
Next

End Sub
```